# Not able to start Hadoop CLuster

Tags: hadoop

I am getting below error: when i am trying to start hadoop cluster

kishan@kishan-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.9.1.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection refused
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.9.1.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-kishan-resourcemanager-kishan-VirtualBox.out
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Comment: `connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection refused`... Hadoop won't start an SSH server for you. That's a prerequisite to running anything

Comment: Also, if you're using virtualbox anyway, Hortonworks and Cloudera already give you pre-installed images